# An Inequality In Information Theory

Tags: information-theory, entropy

I know that for discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$,

$H(X,Y) \geq  H(X)$ and $H(X,Y) \geq  H(Y)$

My question is, given that $A and B$ are continuous random variables, is there any continuous counterpart of this inequality, that is,

$h(A,B) \geq  h(A)$ and $h(A,B) \geq  h(B)$

Comment: By chain $h(A,B)= h(A)+h(B|A)$ if $ h(B|A)$ is non-negative than it is true. The problem is tha $h(B|A)$ can be negative.

Comment: @Boby I think you should turn that into an answer

Comment: @leonbloy done.

Answer (score 4):

By the chain rule one gets
\begin{align}
h(A,B)= h(A)+h(A|B).
\end{align}
However, note that $h(A|B)$ might be negative. Therefore,
the inequality
\begin{align}
h(A,B)\ge  h(A)
\end{align}
holds if and only if $h(A|B) \ge 0$.

An example of $h(A|B) <0$ can be constructed as follows:
\begin{align}
A=B+W
\end{align}
where $B$ is independent of $W$ and $W \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$. Therefore,
\begin{align}
h(A|B)=h(W)=0.5 \log (2 \pi e \sigma^2),
\end{align}
to make $h(A|B)$ negative take $\sigma^2<\frac{1}{2 \pi e}$.

Comment: Just for completeness' sake, perhaps you should add an example where $h(A|B) <0$.

Comment: Done. See the example.